# How to combine datasets in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'd like to combine 2 datasets in Pig but am a little confused as to how to do it.

Say I have `aliasA` with

```
qwe 0
rty 0
asd 0
```

And `aliasB` with

```
dfgg 0
dgfg 0
```

Both have the same column names, column1 for both is `Name` and column2 for both is `id` which isn't like a primary key or anything.

Is there a way to simply combine the 2 sets without anything fancy? A full outer join doubles the # of columns, which I don't want.

Basically, I want

```
qwe 0
rty 0
asd 0
dfgg 0
dgfg 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [UNION](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#union) operator, which does exactly what you want. It combines relations into one, but under one condition: all of the relations used in the `UNION` must have a known schema, which by what you have said it is not your problem. Use `ONSCHEMA` to base the union on named fields.

```
aliasA = LOAD 'data1' AS (Name:chararray,id:int);
DUMP aliasA;
(qwe,0)
(rty,0)
(asd,0)

aliasB = LOAD 'data2' AS (Name:chararray,id:int);
DUMP aliasB;
(dfgg,0)
(dgfg,0)

X = UNION aliasA, aliasB;
DUMP X;
(qwe,0)
(rty,0)
(asd,0)
(dfgg,0)
(dgfg,0)
```